# HTML/JavaScript add onClick action

Tags: javascript

i want to create a website and stacking on the login-page. You got a button and if you click on it a bigger window will pop up. After typing in username and password a Welcome message will appear.

Now i want that after some seconds of the message my new html page should appear, but i dont really know how it works, tried many things.

And i also want to know, if i wrote something wrong in the conditions of the username and password, because every time i want to add a condition like: if username="Schmid" then an alert should pop up.

Thank you very much for your help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){


 $("#form_before_lounch").click(function() {
 
 $(this).animate({height:"250px",width:"400px"});
 $(this).children("p").animate({fontSize:"25px"});
 
 $("#form").delay(500).fadeIn();

  
 })
 $("#submit").click(function(){
 
 var u_name = $("#username").val();
 var pass = $("#password").val();
 
 if (u_name != "" && pass != "") {
 
   $("#form_before_lounch").fadeOut();
   $("h1").fadeIn();
   $("h1").html("Welcome " +u_name);
   $("h1").animate({marginTop:"200px"});
 
 
 
 };
 
 })
 
 

});
</script>
```

```css
* {
 
margin:0px;
padding:0px; 

}
body {
 background:url("LogInBackground.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
 background-size: 100% 100%;
 
}
#form_before_lounch {
 
 width:100px;
 height:35px;
 background:#333;
 position:absolute;
 left:50%;
 top:50%;
 transform:translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 cursor:pointer;
}

#form_before_lounch > p {
 
 color:white;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 text-align:center;
 line-height:35px;
}

#form {
 display:none;
 width: 350px;
 height:200px;
 margin: 0px auto;
 margin-top:5px;
}
#form > div > div{
 
 width:250px;
 height:40px;
 margin:0px auto;
 margin-bottom:10px;
}

#form > div > div > input {
 
 width: 250px;
 height: 35px;
 background:transparent;
 color:white;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 
 
}
#form > div > #btn {
 
 width:100px;
 height:35px;
 margin:0px auto;
}

#form > div > #btn > #submit {
 width:100px;
 height:35px;
 
}
h1 {
 color:white;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:sans-serif;
 display:none;
 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

     <title>Animated Log In Form</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="LogInStylesheet.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"type="text/javascript" ></script>
  </head>
<body>



<h1></h1>


   <section id="form_before_lounch">

   <p>Log In</p>

   <form id="form" method="post" onsubmit="return false">
     <div>
        <div>
   
           <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username"/>
   
        </div>
      <div>
   
           <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/>
   
      </div>
   
   
     <div id="btn">
   
      <input type="button" id="submit" value="Log In"/>
   
   </div>


</div>

</form>


</section>

</body>
</html>
<script>
```

Comment: There is an error when you run your code: {
  "message": "SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'",
  "filename": "http://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 138,
  "colno": 4
}

Comment: A javascript login is to be considered completly insecure. There is no alert for a username "Schmidt". And I'm not shure what you want to do. Your form submit should make a request to a server to check login credentials. And the response can then be a redirect to your real page. It seems like you're trying to achive something with javascript, that it is not made for.